# Cannot add Transition Links by Process Template Editor for Visual Studio 2019 and TFS 2018

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-addins, tfs-process-template

I use a Visual Studio 2019 CE and a TFS 2018 Update 3.

I installed the Process Template Editor from the Marketplace: [download site](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.msdevlabs-pte&ssr=false#overview)

Here you can edit the WITs like in the old editor. In the 'Workflow' tab I can edit and modify everything, I can even add new 'State' items. But It seems I cannot add a new 'Transition Link'. Has someone an idea how to make that work? Maybe I missed something or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Workflow]

Outside of the Work Item Types (WIT) pane there is a `Toolbox` tab that opens up a WITDesigner control panel.

To make a transition link you must first select Transition Link in the control panel. You'll then move into the WIT pane where **you must select the starting state, then select the state that's being transitioned to**. Dragging the transition link is disabled.

In other words, to add transition link, there should be a starting state and target state. Hope this helps.
[image]